# Window.focus() fails in Firefox 24

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox xul extension.

In extension I get a DOM element on web page and I want to focus the window it belongs to.

The code is:

```
this.src.ownerDocument.defaultView.focus();
```

But it fails to focus that window in Firefox 24.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Is there any preference which controls this?

Comment: What's "this.src" supposed to be? Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I have talked before, this is a general DOM element.

Comment: If add the whole code, it will be too large and I think the code i attached is the key code.